# How to save an image into Core Data (iOS5)

Tags: core-data, ios5, uiimage, nsdata

I have a Binary Data attribute set up in my entity (with Allows External Storage checked), and an image in my app bundle that I want to assign to it (test.jpg). What is the best way?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *item = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" 
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
[item setValue:??? forKey:@"image"];
```